# Sublime 3 - custom error color style

Tags: sublimetext3

Is it possible to change color of the underscore pointing to the error location ?

I tried to edit color scheme, but I can't find which XML tag is responsible/coloring this feature.

First line is how is it now. The second one how it should be.

[image]

Comment: where is this underscore pointing to the error location coming from? some package you have installed?

Comment: Error location. Exact place (text column number).